# Change date format to dd/mm/yyyy in sql

Tags: sql, date, putty, sql-date-functions

I have a table called users and In sql the format of date is yyyy-mm-dd
there fore when I try to enter data from my website in dd/mm/yyyy format it just enters 0000--00-00
How do I change the format it sql?

Comment: http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/date-and-time-functions/mysql-str_to_date-function.php

Comment: But this doesn't change the format permanately

Comment: The datetime column has yyyy-mm-dd format.If you want to enter dates with another format use str_to_date with the format you have.(dd/mm/yyyy)

Comment: you can't change the format, to save data in format dd/mm/yyyy you have to save it as a varchar field, but this is not feasible, it will give issues later. Modify your data before saving

Comment: which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: Putty is what I am using

Comment: PuTTY isnt a sql database as far as i am aware. What is the database being used?  This is essential because every dbms has different methods/functions for dates. In most databases date information is NOT stored in a readable format but stored as numbers. So if your data is literally stored by a format it is a string and that's usually a very bad way to handle dates.

Answer (score 2):

SQL Server Example

[Link below has an easy explanation and there's an example if it helps](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_convert.asp)

```
SELECT convert(varchar, getdate(), 103) – dd/mm/yyyy
```

Or try putting your column name in place of "datecolumn"

```
CONVERT(varchar(19), datecolumn, 103)
```

Comment: Just to add, without knowing anything more about your question this is the general basic answer in SQL. Definitely would consider the post comments on your question.

Comment: This answer is specific to T-Sql which you haven't stated. If trying it in another dbms it will cause error.

Comment: Yes you are correct, post was a few years back, I must have confused it with the CAST function. Post edited.

Answer (score 1):

in SQL Server, according to the article [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189491.aspx)

```
SET DATEFORMAT YMD;
```

Comment: This is awesome to read data in dmy format as in asian countries. For that `SET DATEFORMAT dmy;`

Answer (score 0):

No Idea what data getting entered as 0000-00-00  and where zeros coming from , but this may help:
Basically , Data in a Date column in Oracle can be stored in any user defined format or kept as default.
It all depends on NLS parameter.

Current format can be seen by : SELECT SYSDATE FROM DUAL;

If you try to insert a record and insert statement is NOT in THIS format then it will give :
ORA-01843 : not a valid month  error.
So first change the database date format before insert statements ( I am assuming you have bulk load of insert statements) and then execute insert script.

Format can be changed by :
ALTER SESSION SET nls_date_format = 'mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss';

Also You can Change NLS settings from SQL Developer GUI , (Tools > preference> database > NLS)

Ref: http://oracle.ittoolbox.com/groups/technical-functional/oracle-sql-l/how-to-view-current-date-format-1992815

Answer (score 0):

If data is being saved but is showing up in your database as 0000-00-00 that'll usually be because you have the date field set to default at null.

Same thing happened to me. Once you turn that off it'll save the data as normal.

Worth also bearing in mind that you may need to ensure your code is being formatted properly when it reaches the database (if you happen to be posting data from a browser to the database. This will usually help to sort it:

$dateForDB = DateTime::createFromFormat('d-m-Y', $_POST['whateverYourDateVariableIsCalled']);
$dateForDB = $dateForDB->format('Y-m-d');

Hope that helps :)

Answer (score 0):

```
(SELECT Top 1  REPLACE(CONVERT(CHAR(11), SendDate, 106),' ','-')  FROM tbl_EmpDoc WHERE UniqueId=@UniqueId) AS  SendDate
```