# How to set SQL date time format to mm/dd/yy with no time in linked tables?

Tags: sql, sql-server, ms-access

I linked my Access table to SQL Server backend. During the conversion the date time format got changed to SQL date time format. Now instead of showing date as `mm/dd/yy` , the linked table is showing date and time as `YEAR-MONTH-DAY 00:00:00.0000000` which is coming from the SQL server `datetime` datatype.

How to I change the format of the data type back to simple `mm/dd/yy` without any time showing?

Comment: Dates/times have no inherent format, it's only how they are displayed in a client app that changes.

Comment: A date/time value is actually stored as a number. The date/time structure you see is a default display of the database. You can choose other formats for display. With Access tables, this format can be defined in table, which I don't do and no idea if SQLServer allows that. Do formatting on forms and reports. Format property setting does not change the saved value. Format() function results in a string value, not a true full date/time.

Comment: You can change `datetime` type to `date` in the sql table or `cast(datetimeField as date)` in a `select` query.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change date format to dd/mm/yyyy in sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20741750/change-date-format-to-dd-mm-yyyy-in-sql)

Comment: SELECT FORMAT( GETDATE(), 'MM/dd/yyyy') AS 'DateTime Result' --starting in SQL 2012

Comment: I think it would be better to change the format in the table but 
Alter table dbo.INV
 Alter column DAT convert(nvarchar, DAT, 101); does not work

Comment: I get "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'convert'." error

Answer (score 2):

So I used SQL Server Migration Assistant to link tables. From SQL Server Docs they want us to use datatime2 instead of datetime datatype. For this reason i guess while automatic conversion they changed the datatype to datetime2. All I had to do was go to SQL server change the datatype to datetime and refresh table link in my linked table. Access then assumes than uses the date/time datatype to display the date front end and ignores the time automatically. You guys were right about this

> Dates/times have no inherent format, it's only how they are displayed
>   in a client app that changes

Comment: That is correct. The other method is to use the newer [Microsoft® ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server®](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=56567) which will read _DateTime2_ as true date values understood by VBA.